# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.getState

Tags: jsf, indexoutofboundsexception, state-saving

When I use this code without `<p:tab>` it works as expected,

```
<h:form>
    <p:wizard>
        <p:tab title="Test-1">
            <h:form>
                <p:growl id="msg"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{studentController.departmentIDgenerate}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{departmentController.departmentList}" var="deparet" itemLabel="#{deparet.departmentName}" itemValue="#{deparet.departmentId}"/>
                    <p:ajax listener="#{studentController.addMessage}" update="msg"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>            
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Test-2">
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

but when I start using `<p:tab>`, it throws the below exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.getState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.getState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:100)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by removing the outer `h:form` (form that wraps the `<p:wizard>` ) cause you got a nested forms here (which is bad)

Comment: @Daniel, can you please advise about similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830997/how-to-figure-out-the-cause-of-stringindexoutofboundsexception-in-serversidestat

Comment: @MahmoudS, sorry, no idea about what could cause that stacktrace.